# Google Fit Authorization : AUTH_DENIED Authorization cancelled

Tags: android, react-native, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

***I need immediate help about Authorization.***

**I cannot Authorize to Google Fit.** I get **AUTH_DENIED Authorization cancelled** in my console. Here is what I did step by step. I am going to get crazy about it.

This is my function where I am trying to Authorize:

```
  const onCheckGoogleFit = () => {
    const options = {
      scopes: [
        Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ,
        Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_WRITE,
        Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ,
        Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_WRITE,
      ],
    };
    GoogleFit.authorize(options)
      .then((authResult) => {
        if (authResult.success) {
          console.log("AUTH_SUCCESS", authResult);
        } else {
          console.log("AUTH_DENIED", authResult.message);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("AUTH_ERROR");
      });
  };
```

I did all the steps in this documentation:

To get SHA-1 Key, I ran this command in my RN project directory **myProject/android/app** :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ./debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: May 18, 2021
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=...
Issuer: CN=...
Serial number: ...
Valid from: Tue May 18 11:29:52 TRT 2021 until: Sat Oct 03 11:29:52 TRT 2048
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: [I got the key here.]
         SHA256: ...
Signature algorithm name: ...
```

**Then in console.cloud.google.com:**

1. I enabled Google Fitness API
2. I created new credentials for OAuth2 (selected User Data.)
3. Skipped Scopes(optional)
4. Application Type:Android
5. Package Name founded from AndroidManifest.xml file. (com.example)
6. Pasted SHA-1 Key which is taken from
   RNProject/android/app/debug.keystore(like in output above)
7. Successfully got Client ID.

**My RNProject/android/build.gradle I have this:**

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
}
```

***And I added this:***

```
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
```

**My RNProject/android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies{
    // for google-fit
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
}
```

Comment: Is this of any help? https://github.com/StasDoskalenko/react-native-google-fit/issues/123

Comment: Hi Andy. I tried this also but still no solution

Comment: Hi @OğuzhanYıldırım, you would have to do the permission request before to get successful authorization.
[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization#requesting_android_permissions)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Skipped Scopes". You are requesting for some of the fitness scopes. Did you configure that your project would use these scopes on the cloud console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution. My steps were right. I just followed 2 steps to solve the problem.

1. I changed my Package Name as **(com.example.app)** like in `android/app/build.gradle` in `defaultConfig(applicationId)`. I used it as **(com.example)** at the first time like in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
2. I added my google account as a test user in **console.cloud.google.com**

And everything worked perfectly :)

Comment: 2. I added my google account as a test user in console.cloud.google.com'

Thank god you are here !

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I lost the keystore.jks key. I created a new keystore.jks and released a new build to play store. Thats where i experienced this issue. I had to redo the steps on console.cloud.google.com and pasted new SHA-1 key and got a clientID. Things where then working fine.